# What kind of nest is this in my attic?

Tags: pest-control

I heard some noise coming from the attic last night. Went up today and found this.
There is another like this about 12ft away.
Isn't it too big to be a mice nest?
I couldn't take a closer look because the ladder I was using was not very stable.
Gonna try and get a new ladder and do a closer inspection tomorrow.

[image: nest in the attic]

Comment: Seems like it might be a better fit for [outdoors.se] or maybe [gardening.se] - read their rules for what's on topic.

Answer (score 1):

Mice I know do not make surface nests.

It could be squirrel, failed bird nest or even raccoon.

It all depends what kind of wild life you have and how big is the opening for visitors to come in.

Comment: To add: you need to find the opening. This is getting in somehow.

Comment: And trap and evict the nest occupants _before_ sealing the opening. Else there will be several more openings made in quick order...